# How to have Python recall a filename using a query search?

Tags: python, file

```
import os 
path=r'C:\Users\User\Documents\prog'
folderlist=os.listdir(path)


def is_file_contain_word(folderlist,query_word):
for file in folderlist:
    if query_word in open(folderlist).read():
        print (file)
print("finishing searching.")

query_word=input("please enter the keyword:")

is_file_contain_word(folderlist,query_word)
```

This is what I have so far. It has returned that I have type error:

```
invalid file: ['1.doc', '1.odt', 'new.txt']
```

I got this error when I swapped path with folderlist in the open

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\God\\Documents\\prog' 
import os
```

This is my new code:

```
import os

path=r'C:\Users\God\Documents\prog'
folderlist=os.listdir(path)
print(folderlist)

def is_file_contain_word(folderlist,query_word):
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if query_word in i:
            print("Found %s" %query_word)
        else:
            print("not found")
query_word=input("please enter the keyword:")

is_file_contain_word(path,query_word)
```

This goes through each of the 3 files to search for the filename. It only stops when it finds it or it goes through it.

Comment: `folderlist` is a python `list`. You cannot open a list. You can instead open a file name.

Comment: You likely wanted `open(file).read()` instead of `open(folderlist).read()`. However, you shouldn't use the built-in name `file` for your variable name. It happens to share the name with a built-in for python.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX: FWIW, it looks like the OP is using Python 3.  If so, `file` isn't a builtin name any more and is a perfectly cromulent variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making multiple mistakes here:

First, try to indent your code correctly:

```
def is_file_contain_word(folderlist,query_word):
    for file in folderlist:
        if query_word in open(folderlist).read():
            print (file)
    print("finishing searching.")
```

Then the real problem.
`open(folderlist)` should be `open(file)`, as I believe that's your intention.
And that's one reason why the program won't run: `open(folderlist)` opens `C:\Users\User\Documents\prog`, which is a directory and will cause problem.(You probably thought this line opens all files contained in that folder)
BTW, don't use "file" as a var, it's a reserved word in python.

However, even though you fix this part, the original function still won't work.

```
def is_file_contain_word(folderlist,query_word):
    for f in folderlist:
        if query_word in open(f).read():
            print (f)
    print("finishing searching.")
```

Why? If you check this folderlist(`folderlist=os.listdir(path)`), it would be something like:

```
["Prog's Movies", "Homework3.pdf", "blahblah.txt"]
```

Which is problematic because first, you can't open them because they aren't absolute path(Like `C:\Users\God\Documents\prog\blahblah.txt`), second, `listdir` would also list all directories(In this case "Prog's Movies" directory), which you can't use `open` to open them.

At last, if you are running this on command line, don't make two `folderlist` vars. I know in this case it won't cause problem, but it dose reduce your code's readibility and seem to confuse you a little bit.

**How to fix it?**
[How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)
Here is a nice answer to how to open all files in a directory correctly.

Comment: <pre><code>import os

path=r'C:\Users\God\Documents\prog'
folderlist=os.listdir(path)
print(folderlist)

def is_file_contain_word(folderlist,query_word):
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if query_word in i:
            print("Found %s" %query_word)
        else:
            print("not found")
query_word=input("please enter the keyword:")

is_file_contain_word(path,query_word)</code>

Comment: @user3007632 Still not quite right. Plz read the answer that I linked to, as you only need to modify it a little bit to achieve the result you want. BTW, you need to learn how to format your code. Now it is unreadable.

Comment: marked as the answer, sorry it took this long